# About virtualenv and version of python?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I need help in understanding with venv. I have installed venv with `virtualenv venv -p python3.6.` 
I have activated it (venv) and install django

```
pip django`install django`
```

And so, when I work with my project should I always activate venv or not? Because I run my manage.py without venv and using python2, but I need python3. 
And then I run with active venv with python3 I got mistakes like this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'
```

Answer (score 2):

I also use python3.5.2 and I created a virtual environment using the following command

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

And activated it using the following command

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

I always activate the virtual environment before running the application

Answer (score 1):

You must activate the virtualenv before calling `pip install ...` (potentially using `pip3` with Python 3.x) and also every time you need to work with the virtualenv (e.g. before calling `python manage.py ...`)

Comment: Thank you. Than so It shows that I always worked with python2 interpreter from the system but I have a construction like this    def __str__(self): return self.name in my models.py. This construction using only in python3 or not?

Comment: That should be ok in Py3, and probably also if you're using Python2, but don't have non-unicode data in self.name. Writing code that supports both Py2/Py3 is notoriously difficult (compared to what you would normally expect), so my advise would be to choose one and stick with it.

Comment: I dont have a problem with running my project with python2 and when I activate venv and start to use python3 I got the mistake 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'' , should I reinstall django in pip3 or what to do?

Comment: If you want to use django in the virtualenv containing Python 3, then you need to install django in that virtualenv.